# The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects. Parameter name: value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a register page that saves the data to a database the only problem is when I click the register button I am getting an error which im not too sure how to solve, please see below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your declaring `param[]` to have 6 elements, but you're only using 5. The last one is `null` so you're getting the error on the last iteration of your for loop where you add the elements to the `SqlParameterCollection`.

It would be much cleaner/easier to do the following rather than declaring an array, filling the array, and then trying to copy the array:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", gender);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", age);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", address);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", email);
```

Comment: works fine that thanks but now come across another error - Insert Error:Cannot open database "SJDatabase" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user